# How to fix custom function class not registered in apache jena fuseki error?

Tags: jena, fuseki, jena-rules

I need a custom filter function in apache-jena-fuseki. I tried adding custom function class name to config.ttl. I added function class files to class path. But it's always throwing error that function is not registered.

Can anyone please share a detailed approach I can try or some documentation? Desperately need it.

Added following line To Configuration File

```
[] ja:loadClass "org.apache.jena.sparql.function.library.function" .
```

Class file is in folder /home/user/custom_functions/

Class file package name = org.apache.jena.sparql.function.library.

Java command to launch fuseki server is

```
java -cp /home/user/custom_functions/function.class:/home/user/apache-jena-4.5.0/lib-src/*:/home/user/apache-jena-4.5.0/lib/* -jar fuseki-server.jar
```

Function takes one argument.
When I run query, it gives me error log that function has not registered FunctionFactory.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX java: <http://www.w3.org/2007/uwa/context/java.owl#>
PREFIX f: <java:org.apache.jena.sparql.function.library.>
SELECT ?s ?o { 
    ?s rdfs:label ?o . 
    FILTER (f:function(?o) ) .
}
```

Comment: Please check [ask], take the [tour] and edit your question with the concrete steps that you have tried and what exactly was the outcome (and expectation). So far you just state _that_ you did _something_. Just asking for documentation is explicitly off topic here (see [help/on-topic])

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: (1) Don't use `org.apache.jena.sparql.function.library`, use your own package structure Java does not like split packages. (2) you don't need loadClass if you use `<java:...>`, it just has to be on the classpath  (3) Java Class file does not go in in folder /home/user/custom_functions/ - java loads by package name being a directory hierarchy. the cp needs to point to the root of classfiles, and then a directory structure under that has your code in it.

Comment: (4) If you have -cp and -jar, -cp is ignored -- it's one or the other. -jar will not work for adding classes. The "main" is `org.apache.jena.fuseki.main.cmds.FusekiMainCmd`

Comment: hi @AndyS, what would be root of class files in src/main/java/arq/examples/filter/classify.java ? src folder or java folder?

Comment: Your choice. It must agree with the URI : `<java:my.choice.of.class>`

Comment: @AndyS Thank you it worked. I figured what I was doing wrong. -cp and -jar can not be put together.